# How to run Activities as a separate task in android?

Tags: android

In Google Chrome, every chrome window is run as a separate task and can be killed by user from recent. How can i accomplish this feature in my app ?

Comment: Probably you can make a generic separate app containing several Activities what are not interconnected. Then you can pass some parameters via URL-Scheme to start the app with a specific activity in foreground.
The complex part in this task is data transportation between activities-processes, but it depends on the app you want to create.

Comment: @RomaBugaian that sounds limited though, and I think they'd still share the same `Application` instance, and thus same process.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, there will be only two processes. Maybe there is a way to start several instances of an app?

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with `android:process=":remote"`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Generally it is used with services or receivers, but I am not sure that it works with activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in detail in the [guide to the Overview Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html) (aka Recent Apps). Briefly, you can either:

- ensure your activity is launched with the intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` (and optionally `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` to allow the same document to be openable twice at once as duplicate tasks)
- or, set `android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting"` on your activity in your manifest (or `"always"` for the duplicate tasks behaviour).

Comment: Thanks bro, its perfect solution :)